# OOL (out of line) code

Tags: javascript, compiler-construction, ionmonkey

What is OOL (Out of line) code? I've found it in ION compiler but can't understand what is going on.

```
bool CodeGeneratorShared::generateOutOfLineCode() {
  for (size_t i = 0; i < outOfLineCode_.length(); i++) {
    // Add native => bytecode mapping entries for OOL sites.
    // Not enabled on asm.js yet since asm doesn't contain bytecode mappings.
    if (!gen->compilingAsmJS()) {
        if (!addNativeToBytecodeEntry(outOfLineCode_[i]->bytecodeSite()))
            return false;
    }

    if (!gen->alloc().ensureBallast())
        return false;

    JitSpew(JitSpew_Codegen, "# Emitting out of line code");

    masm.setFramePushed(outOfLineCode_[i]->framePushed());
    lastPC_ = outOfLineCode_[i]->pc();
    outOfLineCode_[i]->bind(&masm);

    outOfLineCode_[i]->generate(this);
  }

  return !masm.oom();
}
```

I've tried to use google to found information about it, but didn't have a success. Maybe you can give me some idea what it is? Thank you :)

Comment: Can you link the source, please?

Comment: All code is so big. I only attach the method where out of line code is generating. So all code you can clone from https://archive.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/js/

Comment: Thanks, yes, but from which file in which zip archive (or which engine version) is this specifically?

Comment: I can't speak for the specific use here, but out-of-line code is sometimes used to describe code that is not emitted IN line, i.e. when you emit a call to a stand-alone routine rather than emitting the code directly into the current location.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I looked into the source, and it seems that "out of line" here means code that's generated after the normal code/function.

See e.g. `CodeGenerator::generate` basically looks like this:

```
generateProlog();
generateBody();
generateEpilog();
generateOutOfLineCode();
```

So out of line code is generated after the code's end. This is often used for exceptional control flow and to keep the code that invokes deoptimization, throws exception, etc. out of the instruction cache and the "normal" program code.

Let's assume we have a function `int f(int a, int b) { return a / b; }` and the languages semantics force us to throw an Exception if the divisor is 0. This is the code in pseudo assembly:

```
  cmp b, 0
  jump-if-not-zero lbl1
  call throw_exception

lbl1:
  div c, a, b
  ret c
```

You can see that normal program flow needs to jump over the code that throws the exception. Usually b is non-zero in almost all cases so that seems kind of wasteful. With out of line code we can generate more efficient code:

```
  cmp b, 0
  jump-if-zero out-of-line1
  div c, a, b
  ret c

out-of-line1:
  call throw_exception
```

Here we only jump for zero values which should be rare. The `cmp` and `div` instruction are also nearer to each other which is good for instruction cache usage.

In my JIT I am generating out of line code for null pointer exception throwing, failing asserts, etc. JS and IonMonkey may use it for different operations. One example for out of line code I've found is class `OutOfLineTruncateF32OrF64ToI32` for WASM, that extends `OutOfLineCode` the base class of all out of line code.

What's also nice is that out of line code in IonMonkey can use the field `rejoin` to jump back to normal code flow.